# ASP .net 4.0 CSS .page width not applying

Tags: asp.net, .net, css, .net-4.0

First question, be nice! ;-)

Working with Visual Studio 2010, I have created a basic Framework 4.0 Website from the normal C# Web Site template.  I am now looking to edit the .css that was given by MS.

Just as a proof of concept I would like to take the default 960px .page width and change it to 550px.  I have changed this manually via the code directly and I've also tried via the Manage Styles toolbar.  The new width applies in the Design view, but when running in a browser I can confirm by inspecting the applied style that it is always 960px.  (Changing 960 to 550 in Firefox's css editor works...)

I have restarted VS2010, my computer, I have rebuilt the Solution, rebuilt the web site and published to IIS externally.  The .css I am editing is not applying to my page.

```
.page
{
    width: 550px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid #496077;
}
```

For those who may be even less familiar with VS2010 than I am, this .page style appears to be the only place that has a stated width, and at 960px does indeed set the width for the whole site.  The .css file I am working with is the generated one located at |ProjectDirectory|/Styles/Site.css

Any ideas?

Comment: are you refreshing the page (old css file may be cached), also try `width-max: 550px;`

Comment: Have you tried clearing the browser cache?  Also, have you made sure you saved the css document.  That one bites me every so often.

Comment: Well, I ctrl-f5 all day at work:  Never thought I'd forget to do it at home.  Thanks gents, that was it.  Been beating my head against a nonexistent problem since last night!